How to check if an item is in the root folder?
How to check if an item is in the root folder?
I have an array with all folders allFolders, from it I need to get the ROOT folder, knowing only one of the subfolders
const selectedFolder = {id: 6, parent_id: 5, children: []};

const allFolders = [
  {
    id: 1, // ROOT
    parent_id: null,
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        parent_id: 1,
        children: [{ id: 3, parent_id: 2, children: [] }],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 4, // ROOT
    parent_id: null,
    children: [
      {
        id: 5,
        parent_id: 4,
        children: [{ id: 6, parent_id: 5, children: [] }],
      },
    ],
  },
];

I need to get the root folder knowing only one of the subfolders, now I'm trying to do this:
let nestedFolderMove = [];
     const addChild = el => {
     if (selectedFolder?.parent_id === el?.id) {
       nestedFolderMove.push(...el.children);
     }
       return el.children.map(addChild).flat();
     };

allFolders?.map(addChild).flat(); // need root {id: 4, parent_id: null, children: ...}


This looks like homework, so I’m only going to give hints. Your code is only checking the root level of the folder tree, so it won’t work when the parent isn’t on that root level. You would need to recursively traverse each folder’s children in order to find the parent of any given node. That said, it looks like this is a sorted tree, so there’s a more efficient way to do the traversal.

an item is on root folder if its parent_id is null. if it isn't then you can do a while loop go up the parent_id tree until you reach null
